# Countability assumption for good covers in Bott-Tu

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology, differential-forms, derham-cohomology, cech-cohomology

In chapter II of their text *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*, Bott and Tu construct the Čech-De Rham complex with regards to an open covering indexed by some ordered and countable indexing set. I fail to see where this assumption is needed - to me all the constructions seem to work for arbitrary coverings, as long as a order on the indexing set is fixed.

A little later in the text, the coincidence of  De Rham and the Čech cohomology of a good cover is then applied to arbitrary covers (Prop. 10.6). Is this implicitly invoking the second-countability of the manifold (does this even work)?